# Creating Ascii raster file from matrix without rotation in r

Tags: r, raster

I have a matrix map without a header. Let's say I have the data below:

```
set.seed(123)
r <- matrix(runif(16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
```

I applied `epi.asc`:

```
library(epiR)
epi.asc(r, file="r.asc", xllcorner=414495.02518863, yllcorner=4427573.131968, cellsize=27.258893080917, na = -9999)
```

However, when I check the asc output file, orders of columns and rows are changed. Applying `t(r)` is also not a solution. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

With your example data

```
set.seed(123)
r <- matrix(runif(16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
cellsize=27.258893080917
lowleft <- c(414495.02518863, 4427573.131968)
```

You can do

```
upright <- lowleft + dim(r) * cellsize 
library(terra)
x <- rast(r)
ext(x) <- as.vector(rbind(lowleft, upright))

x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 4, 4, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 27.25889, 27.25889  (x, y)
#extent      : 414495, 414604.1, 4427573, 4427682  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. :  
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :     lyr.1 
#min value   : 0.0455565 
#max value   : 0.9568333
```